# How can I calculate the data energy loss after PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, pca, linear-algebra

Recently in a slide in about `PCA` (Principal Component Analysis) I saw a question: "How much is the data energy loss in `PCA`?" Then in the next slide I saw somethings that do not understand relation of last steps to the `PCA` and energy. Although I know that `PCA` tries to find principle components which have variances in decreasing order and also guess the energy means the total variance after keeping some first principle components and applying it on normalized data; but in this way I think what is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) as `cumulative energy content for each eigenvector` and what is described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22571), are more rational and understandable.

Here you can see part of slide that tries to show an example:

[image]

Steps are:

1. `X` as input
2. normalize `X` (as `Z`)
3. compute covariance matrix of `Z` as `R`
4. eigenvalues of `R` in descending order as $\lambda$ and their corresponding vectors as `V`.
5. $S = V\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is element-wise operation.
6. discard third column of `S` and sore it as `S`
7. calculate diagonal elements of $S S^{T}$ as `var` columnar matrix
8. `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA`. Here it is `1 - 0.8420`.

This is an `Octave` code that you can follow to get the same results:

```
X=[
7 4 3;4 1 8;6 3 5;8 6 1;8 5 7;
7 2 9;5 3 3;9 5 8;7 4 5;8 2 2];

rows=size(X)(1);
XMean = repmat(mean(X),rows,1);
XStd = repmat(std(X),rows,1);
X_normalized = (X - XMean)./(XStd);

Cov_mat=cov(X_normalized);

[V,lambda] = eigs(Cov_mat) %descending order
S = V * lambda^(0.5);
S1 = S(:,1:2);
var = diag(S1*S1')
```

Here are what I do not understand:

- What is the definition of `energy loss` of PCA? If it is relative to what is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), then how is it relative to the steps that here are described in above slide?
- Where can I found a reference or some examples about these steps?
- Why did we keep only first two columns of `S`?
- Why `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA`? Does `2` in `1 - var(2,1)`
  is relative to the first *two* columns?
- Is `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA` by using two eigenvectors relative to the two eigenvectors with largest magnitude?
- If we want to calculate energy loss for only using eigenvector that is relative to the largest eigenvalue, do we have to calculate $[S(1,1) S(1,2) S(1,3)]^T [S(1,1) S(1,2) S(1,3)]$ as `var` and `1 - var(1,1)` is the amount of energy loss?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.